# prop-type warning from react-router Link when using Enzyme's shallow rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, enzyme

When writing tests using Jest and Enzyme I ran into the following error.

> Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `to` is marked as required in `Link`, but its value is `undefined`.

I am generating tests for my Modal component that has a InnerModal with a Link Component. I shallow render the ModalClass and test my handleOpen() function which triggers the prop-types warning.

When I dive() to the Link component rendered by Enzyme, I see that the to line has the proper props passed through from the Enzyme render. I left my console.log functions to depict what I am talking about. The console reads the following.

```
 { to: '/alertpage',
    children:
     { '$$typeof': Symbol(react.element),
       type:
        { [Function: Button]
          defaultProps: [Object],
          _meta: [Object],
          Content: [Object],
          Group: [Object],
          Or: [Object],
          handledProps: [Array],
          propTypes: [Object],
          create: [Function] },
       key: null,
       ref: null,
       props: { children: ' Yes ', as: 'button' },
       _owner: null,
       _store: {} },
    replace: false }
```

It's definitely there, so how do I get rid of this warning?

The code is below.

Unit test:

```js
describe('ModalClass', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow( <ModalClass link={'/alertpage'}/> );
    
     it('modal is open after click button', () => {
        console.log(wrapper.find(InnerModal).at(0).dive().find(Link).props());
        console.log(wrapper.find(InnerModal).at(1).dive().find(Link).props())
        wrapper.instance().handleOpen();
        expect(wrapper.state().open).toBe(true);
    })
    
});
```

ModalClass with functional InnerModal component:

```js
export class ModalClass extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            open: false
        };
    }

    handleOpen = () => this.setState({ open: true });

    handleClose = () => this.setState({ open: false });

    render() {
        return (
        <Modal open={this.state.open}
        trigger={
            <Button onClick={this.handleOpen}>
                <img src={this.props.image} alt="alert" width="100"></img>
            </Button>
            }>
            <Modal.Header> {this.props.modalHeader} </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Content>
                <div class="ui two column centered grid">
                    <InnerModal 
                    buttonLabel={EMERGENCY_ALERT}
                    link={this.props.link}
                    color="red"
                    handleClose={this.handleClose}/>
                    <InnerModal 
                    buttonLabel={TEST_ALERT}
                    link={this.props.link}
                    color="green"
                    handleClose={this.handleClose}/>
                </div>
            </Modal.Content>
        </Modal>
    )
    }
}



export const InnerModal = (props) => {
    return (
        <Modal trigger={
            <Button color={props.color}> {props.buttonLabel} </Button>
        }>
        <Modal.Header> Are you sure you want to send out a {props.buttonLabel}? </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Content>
            <div class="ui two column centered grid">
                <Link to={props.link}><Button> Yes </Button></Link>
                <Button onClick={props.handleClose}> No </Button>
            </div>
        </Modal.Content>
        </Modal>
    )
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: 1. Is it possible that some other component has `Link` in it? 2. How many warnings did you receive? 3. What exactly trigger warnings, `shallow` or calling `handleOpen()`?

Comment: 1.There are other components with Link in them, but the only ones that I know of that are of concern to the ModalClass are ModalClass and InnerModal. 2. There is only one warning when I wrote this test. 3. I believe it is handleOpen since I call shallow multiple times in other tests.

Comment: I also ended up refactoring my code to redirect the user after writing another redux reducer so the error went away... But it still bothers me why it was happening.